# standardize international phone no. code using only regex

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

Sipdroid on Android has a search & replace method, that uses regex.
I'm trying to use it to make sure all outgoing calls has a country code in the format 00XX

I also want it to put 0045 in front of the number, if no country code is present.

The first one, I have solved, but I can't figure out how to do the second thing.

**Search**:

```
\A(((\+)(\d{2})?)|(00(\d{2})?)|)((\d|\s)+)\Z
```

**Replace**:

```
00$4$6$7
```

I'm using http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html to test it, with the test strings: "12345678", "+4512345678" and "004512345678"
They should all return "004512345678".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that country codes may well be 3 or even 4 digits long.

See the [list of country calling codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) for details.

The replacement you are after is quite context-sensitive, so I would guess it is not possible to solve it with a single regex (in a simple enough way to make it actually usable). Then again, I am not a regex guru.

Comment: Well damn. I didn't know.


Guess that makes this almost impossible to pull off, I'll just make it replace + with 00 then

Comment: That probably isn't correct either, if you are concerned about it working for others, that is.

Comment: My main problem is that all my phone numbers in my contact book has numbers in the format +45... but my SIP provider only supports 0045...